# Is there a way to get the exit code of an earlier piped Scala Process (#|)?

Tags: scala, process, pipe, exit-code

I'm trying to pipe commands using scala's sys.process library, but I noticed that `#|` will return the exit code of the final process. I'm having commands earlier in the pipe fail, but the exit code of the final command is 0 as it didn't error out.

I was wondering if scala has a way to check/retrieve if previous commands in the pipe (#|) failed.

```scala
import scala.sys.process._
val p1 = ("false" #| "true").run()
assert(p1.exitValue == 1)
```

Bash has `set -o pipefail` that will pass the non-zero exit-code of a pipe, but it just seems a bit "hacky":

```scala
val p2 = Seq("/bin/bash", "-c", "set -o pipefail && false | true").run()
assert(p2.exitValue == 1)
```

I was hoping there might be a better way.

Thanks, I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2):

[`!!`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/e40c95e6e51b215c8cbb0b9e438fa7a5d5ed8332/src/library/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.scala#L143) operator throws an exception on non-zero exit code, so perhaps it can be used to pass output of one process to the input stream of another via [`#<`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/e40c95e6e51b215c8cbb0b9e438fa7a5d5ed8332/src/library/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.scala#L474) operator only on success. If we define a custom operator `#|<` like so

```
  implicit class Pipefail[T](p1: T) {
    def #|<(p2: T)(implicit ev: T => ProcessBuilder): ProcessBuilder =
      Try(p1.!!).map(result => (p2 #< new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes))).get
  }
```

then we could call it with

```
("false" #|< "true").run
```

which should throw

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
```

whilst

```
("echo Beam Me Up, Scotty" #|< "tr a-z A-Z" #|< "grep -o SCOTTY" ).run
```

should output uppercase `SCOTTY`. This will use [`stringToProcess`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/6fe5f4ff34fef0551952390e3bb3f1ff66d2f807/src/library/scala/sys/process/Process.scala#L214) implicit conversion, so remember to `import scala.sys.process._`